# NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array when checking NSPasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I do a check to validate to make sure copiedItems array has something it in, I am receiving the error: NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

```
NSArray *classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString class], nil]; NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *copiedItems = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
 if ([copiedItems objectAtIndex:0]!= nil){
        NSString *copiedString = [copiedItems objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was causing the error with my check. By calling `[copiedItems objectAtIndex:0]`, I was accessing the array right then, instead of seeing if it was valid first (my original intention). By changing `[copiedItems objectAtIndex:0]` to `if ([copiedItems count]> 0)`
I was able to not access copiedItems until I could validate.

A good expansion from @H2CO3: `[array objectAtIndex:index] != nil` doesn't make sense - NSArrays cannot contain nil

Comment: To expand on this: `[array objectAtIndex:index] != nil` doesn't make sense - `NSArray`s cannot contain `nil`.

Comment: … nor will `objectAtIndex:` return `nil` to indicate an out-of-range index. It raises an exception, as documented.